# How to connect to elasticsearch using boost asio?

Tags: c++, elasticsearch, boost, asio

I'm trying to write a C++ snippet to make a POST to an elasticsearch server.  The server is running on ip 172.20.1.160, and I can PUT data using curl, like in the Elasticsearch tutorial:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1?op_type=create&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
```

{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}
'

But when I try to do something similar with boost ASIO, my connection is apparently refused.

Here's minimal compileable code showing how I try to create the connection, and which produces the error:

```
///   Compiled with:
///     g++ --std=c++14 foo.cpp  -lboost_system -lpthread
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

constexpr const char *carbon_port   = "2003";
constexpr const char *ES_port       = "9200";
constexpr const char *server_ip     = "172.20.1.160";


int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(server_ip, ES_port);
    auto endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket (io_service);
    socket.connect(endpoint);
}
```

For what it's worth, I also have a carbon-graphite server running on the same machine, and I can connect and send data there via the plain-text protocol, but I am unable to make a socket connection to elasticsearch, I get the exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  connect: Connection refused
```

Can someone enlighten me to what I need to know to get this working?

Comment: is the request being sent from same ip ?

Comment: Yes it is.  Does that matter?

Comment: can you try using localhost in place of the IP , just one cent

Comment: OK, that worked!  Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default **elasticsearch** listens to **localhost** only , if you want it to listen to all ports , in `config/elasticsearch.yml` add the line `network.host: 0.0.0.0` and restart elasticsearch.